# How do I check a single value to see if it contains one of 18 values

Tags: vba, range, lookup

I'm trying to do a backwards vlookup.

Have:  Sentences (string)
Looking for:  Keywords (array)

I know I could do a rather crazy compound statement with 
    if(iserr(find("Missing",B1,1)),if(iserr(find("Located",B1,1)),..

But considering I need to use this 1,000 times, and the if then's would be 18 deep. that just doesn't make sense.
I know I can do this with VBA pretty clealy, but I can't seem to figure out the syntax.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Function FindValue(ByRef strToSearch As String, rngLookUpValues As Range) As String
On Err GoTo err_capture
'strToSearch is the sentence I am searching
'rngLookUpValue is a two column Range.
'      The first column is what I'm searching for.  If it exists in the sentence, 
'               return the second column
'      The second column is the category that applies when the word from column one 
'                is found in the sentence

i = 0
For Each row In rngLookUpValues
    i = i + 1
    If InStr(1, strToSearch, row.cell(i, 1).Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        FindValue = row.cell(i, 2).Value
    End If
Next

Exit Function
err_capture:
    Debug.Print Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
End Function
```

When I run this it returns a #Value.  But when I debug it or watch it run, no errors.  It just dies during the instr() function.

Comment: Let's clarify thing: You are calling FindValue in EXCEL , so FindValue is a UDF. 
you are calling FindValue like '=FindValue("Missing", B1:C5)'

You want to match "Missing" against B1:B5, and return that row's Column C's value. 

---> you should use Vlookup

or do you mean by 
= FindValue("Some range of values to match", "Some range of values to match against")

Answer (score 2):

No need for VBA, an array formula will do:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B:$B,MATCH(TRUE,FIND($A:$A,D1)>0,0)),"")
```

where column `B` is the category, column `A` the list of words and `D1` the sentence to check.

Note: Enter the array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>!

For Excel 2003 and your particular example, use this formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(TRUE,FIND('Intake Chart'!$A$2:$A$18,E26)>0,0)),"no match",
INDEX('Intake Chart'!$B$2:$B$18,MATCH(TRUE,FIND('Intake Chart'!$A$2:$A$18,E26)>0,0)))
```

Take a look at [this file](https://mega.co.nz/#!bNYDGZCT!BPRKgWAfqsnCo3_2W1YRrV9NwtNXzCJx1ywxhCn-aEA) - it has exactly the same structure and the working formula.

Comment: Got my vote. It is worth noting that IFERROR is Excel 2007 and later.

Comment: Thanks! I guess by now we can assume that the majority of users uses 2007+ (though I saw from your screenshots that you're still with 2003 ;-) ). But I guess it can hurt to point out to 2003 users, that they can replace `=IFERROR(X,"else")` with `=IF(ISERROR(X),"else",X)`...

Comment: Your right. I'm using 2003.  When I boil this down to =INDEX('Intake Chart'!$B$2:$B$18,MATCH(TRUE,FIND('Intake Chart'!$A$2:$A$18,Data!E26)>0,0)) I get still get the #Value error

Comment: Check the updated answer and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Peter, I'm actually running Excel 2010 for a while now, so not sure why my screenshots look old :). I do have 2003 on a virtual machine, and even have an old 8-track with Excel 97 on it somewhere.

Comment: @DougGlancy: I mixed you up with BonCodigo or one of the other frequent Excel SOer... ;-) Sorry! Similar setup here, just added Excel 2013 in a Win8 VM.

Comment: LOL.  Using a work laptop and this what they run (excel 2003).  Peter, the answer you gave me is still not working.  All response show no match, even when the value being checked (e26) is exactly equal to the value tested against (A2:A18).

Comment: I just checked the 2003 formula again - it was missing a `)` - fixed. Also, I uploaded a file with exactly your layout and the working formula - see the link in the answer.